# ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous-multioutput' instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to do KFold cross-validation on my CNN model in Keras as shown below:

```
X = df.iloc[:,0:10165]  
X = X.to_numpy()                    
X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1])
X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:].reshape(921,10080)          
X_train_2 = X[:,10080:10165,:].reshape(921,85)      
Y = df.iloc[:,10168:10170]

num_classes = 2

cvscores = [] 
for train, test in kfold.split(X_train_1,X_train_2, Y):

    inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10080,1))
    layer1 = Conv1D(64,14)(inputs_1)
    layer2 = layers.MaxPool1D(5)(layer1)
    layer3 = Conv1D(64, 14)(layer2)       
    layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer3)

    inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(85,))
    layer5 = layers.concatenate([layer4, inputs_2])
    layer6 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer5)
    layer7 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(layer6)

    model_2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = [inputs_1, inputs_2], output = [layer7])
    model_2.summary()   

    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0001)
    model_2.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['acc'])

    history = model_2.fit([X_train_1,X_train_2][train], Y[train], epochs = 120, batch_size = 256, callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=50)])


    scores = model.evaluate([X_train_1,X_train_2][test], Y[test], verbose=0)   
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100)) 
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))
```

But I incurred error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-20af389637bd> in <module>()
     11 
     12 cvscores = []
---> 13 for train, test in kfold.split(X_train_1,X_train_2, Y):
     14 
     15     inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10080,1))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _make_test_folds(self, X, y)
    639             raise ValueError(
    640                 'Supported target types are: {}. Got {!r} instead.'.format(
--> 641                     allowed_target_types, type_of_target_y))
    642 
    643         y = column_or_1d(y)

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous-multioutput' instead.
```

From [this post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585227/why-am-i-getting-supported-target-types-are-binary-multiclass-got-con) I realised that I might have to convert `Y` to `binary` so I added `Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y, num_classes)` where `num_classes` is 2, but this didn't work.

What could be the problem? Thanks

---

Edit

The data looks something like this, with last 2 columns as `Y`(labels).

```
id    x0  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5  ... x10079   mean var ... Y0     Y1
1    40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  33       24   1       1      0
2    35  35.75 36.5 26.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29       31   2       0      1 
3    35  35.70 36.5 36.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29       25   1       1      0 
4    40  31.50 23.5 24.5 26.5 25   ...  33       29   3       0      1
 ... 
921  40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  23       33   2       0      1
```

Comment: what does your target look like?

Comment: @NicolasGervais `X` consists of time series(10081 columns) and other descriptive statistics features(85 columns) joint into one row with 921 rows in total. `Y` is `921 x 2` of one hot variables.

Comment: Can you please print out the first few lines of your target?

Comment: @NicolasGervais by target do you mean labels? Please see edited question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59277549/11901732) is related, if it helps to illustrate the problem better